fakeAsync tests fail after switching from es2016 to es2018 or higher
I am working on an upgrade of my project and i wanted to make sure i was using more up to date ECMAScript.
In my tsconfig.spec.json files I had es2016, and i updated it to be 2018, and even tried out es2022.
Most of my tests will pass after changing versions, but I have a small handful that fail now. For example, I have this method that closes and destroys a modal.
  async destroyModal(): Promise<void> {
    const { modalComponentType, modalComponentRef } = this._state$.value;
    document.querySelector('dialog')?.close();
    this.setState({ modalComponentType, modalComponentRef, modalOpen: false }, ModalStateActions.CloseModal);

    // Wait for 300ms for animation before proceeding
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 300));

    // Clear the modal container and notify observers
    this.resetModal();
  }

And I test this like so:
  it('should destroy modal on esc press', fakeAsync(() => {
    service.initModalContainer(hostComponent.componentInstance.viewContainerRef);
    service.createModal(DummyComponent).then(() => verifyModalCreated());
    tick();
    dispatchEscPressEvent();
    tick(500);
    verifyModalDestroyed();
  }));

When using es2016, the test correctly simulates the passage of time and then calls verifyModalDestroyed(). However, when using es2018 or es2022, verifyModalDestroyed() will be called and the test will fail before the Promise resolves inside the destroyModal() method. It is as if tick() has no effect anymore after the update.
Can anyone help me understand that the issue is or what has changed between the versions that these kinds of tests would start failing?

I think the async await is causing the problems in es2018 and higher, so there are other ways to test this type of function. One is to make the test case async await, another is to use then along with done argument of the test case, done determines when the test case is complete.
it('should destroy modal on esc press', async () => {
  spyOn(component, 'resetModal');
  await component.destroyModal();
  expect(component.resetModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
});

it('should destroy modal on esc press', (done) => {
  spyOn(component, 'resetModal');
  component.destroyModal().then(() => {
    expect(component.resetModal).toHaveBeenCalled();
    done();
  });
});

Stackblitz Demo

I have upgraded my project to use es2022 for the build/compile, etc, but my libs are set to still use es2016 for the unit tests only to avoid the breaking changes. Do you see an issues with using different versions for testing, if it makes writing the tests for the code easier?

@CodyPritchard only async functions will have this problem, does my solution help?

Your solution helps me understand the problem, but it does not help me in the test case, as your solution does not rely on my dispatch esc press event. The purpose of the test is to verify that destroyModal() is called within the service when the esc press listener is triggered, not to call it directly. I have a separate test case for that.

@CodyPritchard instead of the tick and fakeasyc try to use these two methods, to make the function wait for the modal to close
